# Parsing yandex search page

Tags: php, parsing, cookies, curl, yandex

When I try to parse yandex search page (http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=...) using php+curl from different proxies (no free, own server with dedicated IP's - more then 100) and i get ban on each 2'nd request from same IP (first request return right result) in a day.

I set all cookies, follow all redirects that browser do, but yandex bans ip even if use new cookies for it, from different browsers.

Who knows what the "secret" operation yandex do, when opening new page? Maybe call some others files, that set some values to sessions.

Needed result: get result page by php+curl more then once from IP with different browsers and cookies.

Comment: Maybe use http://xml.yandex.com/

Comment: Do they not have an API you can use? What sort of header information are you sending?

Comment: I can't use the yandex xml because tests say, that the result is different from pc search and from yandex xml.

Comment: Request redirects to get cookies is: http://www.yandex.ru, http://pass.yandex.ru/?retpath=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yandex.ua, http://pass.yandex.ua/?retpath=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yandex.ua&session_info=noauth%3A1389683781.sah%5EFFFFFFFF.yandexuid%5E955796931389683782.yandex_ua%3A70940.8425.81e941a9eb110ad138a0619c6dcb27b9, http://www.yandex.ua/?ncrnd=6152 and one cookie from http://kiks.yandex.ru/fu. For each request in header also sending Cookies from previous page and Referer URL from it.